# Trying To Make WooCommerce Product Makes Redirect To Affiliate Site

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, affiliate, affiliates

I am trying to edit my Wordpress ecommerce site that is running with woocommerce to become an affiliate shop.

What I want to do is create a shop with lots of product listings and when you click on a product rather than going to the product page on my site the user gets sent to the affiliates product page.

Here is the site I am testing this on http://marijuanahealthfacts.com/ and I am using the wordpress theme http://the7.dream-demo.com/

I appreciate any help and guidance :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a default feature on WooCommerce that you can accomplish by simply setting Affiliate product.

[image]

Comment: Awesome that works for http://legalmedicalmarijuanastates.com/shop/ but people are till able to click on one of the product images and go to a product landing page on my site, which is something I do not want. I want them to click the image and be sent to the affiliate site as well. How can this be accomplished? THANKS!

Comment: Looking for the same. If somebody click on product redirects to affiliate link rather than open a single product page.

Comment: Anybody has some answer? Thanks